# How to render data from sequelize database into express.js render

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

i want to ask.

I have some data from database & want to display into table HTML, how i can render data from database into html page?

This my code from routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const db = require("../models");

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var x = db.Todo.findAll({
            where: {
              id: 2,
            },
            raw: true
          }).then(function(result) {
            return result[0].title);
          });
  res.render('index', { data: x);
})

module.exports = router;
```

And this my code from views/index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-Do list</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>test 1</td>
        <td>test 2</td>
        <td> <%= data.title %> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much for u attention

Comment: You need to loop your response object

Comment: In my router code, i already specified for only return 1 object, and when im refresh my html page, its still dont show anything.